# Sigmoid function returning 2

Tags: python, sigmoid

I just started learning about neural networks and I'm using the `sigmoid` function.

Here's the implementation :

```
def sigmoid(x):
return 1/1+(np.exp(-x))
```

then I have my network :

```
def make_predictions2(previousPrice, currentPrice, weight1, weight2, weight3, bias):
n11 = np.dot(previousPrice, weight1) + np.dot(currentPrice, weight2) + bias
n21 = np.dot(n11, weight3) + bias
n31 = sigmoid(n21)
return n31[0]
```

the problem is that the function is returning `2.0`, but `sigmoid` is only supposed to return numbers between 0 and 1
Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: If x=0, 1/1 is 1, np exp(0) is 1, and 1+1 is 2. Order of operations is a thing.

Comment: So I added parentheses to the divider and now it works perfectly thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Lalaryk consider reformatting your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), that definition of the sigmoid function is wrong. Instead of

```
def sigmoid(x): 
  return 1/1+(np.exp(-x))
```

you should use the following definition:

```
def sigmoid(x): 
  return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```